# Writing system calls - Info about the ABIs : common x32 64

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am exploring system calls in Linux and want to know more about the different ABIs. I can see there are 3 types in the systemcall_64.tbl: common, 64 and x32.

If you can briefly explain each one or point me to some good resources, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.